R circlize add custom Y axis labels
I have a data set looking at frequencies of 57 attributes selected by a panel to describe a the same sample. I've trimmed the data to the first four selections made and want to plot it as a wheel. I've got a lovely graphic up but am having issues with labelling. I've been going around in circles trying to figure it out as it seems like it should be really simple - I hope someone can help!
The data is called TBlended:
structure(c(11, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 15, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 5, 0, 0, 5, 4, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 
1, 1, 5, 3, 5, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 4, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 0, 
4, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 
2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 4, 3, 
3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 6, 0, 1, 0, 4, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3), dim = c(58L, 4L), dimnames = list(c("Feinty", 
"Leathery", "Tobacco", "Sweaty", "Cereal", "Wet cereal", "Dry cereal", 
"Green.grassy", "Leafy", "Herbal", "Green veg", "Floral", "Fresh flowers", 
"Perfumed", "Fruity", "Fresh fruit", "Dried fruit", "Citrus", 
"Artificial", "Solventy", "Soapy", "Sweet", "Vanilla", "Toffee", 
"Honey", "Woody", "Sawdust", "Toasted wood", "Nutty", "Coconut", 
"Nuts", "Toasted nut", "Spicy", "Dried spice", "Black Pepper", 
"Oily", "Buttery", "Oils/fats", "Waxy", "Sour", "Vinegary", "Cheesy", 
"Vomit", "Sulphury", "Cooked veg", "Rubbery", "Struck match", 
"Decaying", "Meaty", "Stale", "Earthy", "Musty", "Metallic", 
"Peaty", "Smoky", "Burnt", "Medicinal", "none"), c("S1", "S2", 
"S3", "S4")))

The working code:
col_fun1 = colorRamp2(c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20), c("grey", "blue", "navy", "purple", "pink"))
circos.par(start.degree = 90, gap.degree = 10)
circos.heatmap(TBlended,
               col = col_fun1, 
               cluster = FALSE,
               track.height = 0.5, 
               rownames.side = "outside")

The basic wheel graphic
I'm trying to add the column labels on the y axis
I've tried this, but I just get a scale of numbers 0 to 4:
circos.yaxis(
  side = "right",
  at = NULL,
  tick = FALSE,
  labels = TRUE,
  sector.index = get.current.sector.index(),
  track.index = get.current.track.index())

I also tried this, but I get an error code:
circos.text(xlim[1] - mm_x(2, h = 1:4), 1:4, 
            paste(S), 
            facing = "downward", adj = c(1, 0.5), cex = 0.8)

EXTRA:
I'd also like to add centralised legend that describes the data scale represented with like this example:
Example
